# How do I pass only certain parameters into the function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in Python. I am unable to pass the required parameters in one function. I am able to pass them in separate functions. Suppose that I am required to slice both the Dataframes and insert the SAME thing on the same INDEX.

I have tried to concatenate both the Dataframes to see which slot is empty.

What I have tried is below

```
def inst(data,people):
    A,B = *data
    length = len(people)
    for item i in range(7-length):
        if not(any(data["Name","Team"][i:i+length])) and len(data)>1:
            DATAFRAMEA["Name","Team"][i:i+length] = people
            DATAFRAMEB["Name","Team"][i:i+length] = people
            return
        elif not(any(data["Name","Team"][i:i+length])) and data == DATAFRAMEA:
            DATAFRAMEA["Name","Team"][i:i+length] = people
            return
        elif not(any(data["Name","Team"][i:i+length])) and data == DATAFRAMEB:
            DATAFRAMEB["Name","Team"][i:i+length] = people
            return




people = [["Lisa","Alex"],["A","D"]]
data = DATAFRAMEA+DATAFRAMEB
inst(data,people)
people = [["James"],["B"]]
inst(DATAFRAMEA,people)
```

DATAFRAME A

```
       Name   Team  
0      John     A    
1      
2   Michael     B     
3    Joanna     C     
4     Sinus     B     
5
6
7
```

DATAFRAME B

```
       Name   Team  
0      John     A    
1      Jane     D
2   Natasha     B     
3    Joanna     C     
4         
5
6
7     Joshua     B
```

How to eliminate the use of elif statements?

Comment: You should probably explain *what* you're trying to do, rather than *how* you're trying to do it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I doubt that your question is specific enough. SO users don't want to copy your code and finish it for you. In this case please use another python forum. You may put a specific error message into your question and ask why your attached code snippet wont work. Please edit your code for easy testing.